# Custom "Create Issue" form per role

Tags: jira

Is it possible to customize the "Create Issue" from per role?

In fact, I simply want to show a reduced set of fields for reporters/users to not overwhelm them and prevent incorrect filling out of unnecessary fields.

Developers should see all fields so that they can provide all necessary/internal details.

Answer (score 1):

In JIRA you can install the plugin "Script Runner" which contains a module called "Behaviours". This module allows you to define fields which should be visible for a specific gruoup or not.

Answer (score 0):

In JIRA we don't have ability to customise this without install plug-ins and edit templates on server-side. Maybe most easy way this is create two different screens in issue screen scheme. First screen(simply) for issue create and second screen(full view) for edit&view.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview